# How can I set the Nhibernate type generator to increment when working with SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

Using HBM files to map my types.

One of my classes uses bag of items called `PartnerEnv`. One of their fields is set to be the id which should be generated using `increment`. for some reason  I am getting the following error:

> could not fetch initial value for increment generator[SQL: SQL not available]
>   Inner details: "{"Invalid object name 'jj.dbo.Partners2Env'."}"

If I change the generation method to `assigned` everything is ok.

I will appreciate any help given!

Comment: Is an ID field in your table an auto increment?

Comment: no, its not. it is a simple int, not null

Answer (score 0):

Can you set your `Id` column on the `PartnerEnv` table (or whatever that table is called) to an `Identity` column and then use the following in the `.hbm` file for that class?

```
<id name="Id" type="Int32">
    <column name="Id" />
    <generator class="identity" />
</id>
```

Comment: I can't change the DB. I was under the impression that using increment let me acheive this without any DB changes

Comment: Understood.  My only other suggestion is to try using `native` instead of `increment`.